# Error: Datatable named "Items" already belongs to this dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

Why am I receiving the error **`Datatable named "Items" already belongs to this dataset`** in the code below?  The error is only occurring when I am attempting to add values where if `((x > 1) || (x == 1))`. I can successfully create multiple new "Item" datatables and then add them to the ds dataset in the while loop, however trying to more than one "AItem" datatable to AllItems dataset causes the error.  The only difference between these datasets is that the ds dataset has many other datatables added to it which have data adapters filling them from a SQL db.

```
DataSet AllItems = new DataSet("Items");
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Header");

foreach (DataRow fieldRow in myDataset.Tables["tempTable"].AsEnumerable())
{
    while (x < 1)
    {
        x++;
        DataTable Item = new DataTable("Item");

        Item.Columns.Add("ID");
        Item.Columns.Add("LineNumber");
        Item.Columns.Add("ItemID");
        Item.Columns.Add("UnitPrice");
        Item.Columns.Add("Description");
        Item.Columns.Add("OrderUOM");
        Item.Columns.Add("OrderQty");

        DataRow aItem = Item.NewRow();
        Item["ID"] = 1.ToString();

        Item["LineNumber"] = x;
        Item["ItemID"] = fieldRow[0].ToString();
        Item["UnitPrice"] = fieldRow[1].ToString();
        Item["Description"] = fieldRow[2].ToString();
        Item["OrderUOM"] = fieldRow[3].ToString();
        Item["OrderQty"] = fieldRow[4].ToString();
        Item.Rows.Add(aItem);

        ds.Tables.Add(Item);
    }



    if ((x > 1) || (x == 1))
    {
        DataTable AItem = new DataTable("AItem");
        Item.Columns.Add("ID");
        Item.Columns.Add("LineNumber");
        Item.Columns.Add("ItemID");
        Item.Columns.Add("UnitPrice");
        Item.Columns.Add("Description");
        Item.Columns.Add("OrderUOM");
        Item.Columns.Add("OrderQty");

        DataRow aItem = Item.NewRow();
        Item["ID"] = 1.ToString();

        Item["LineNumber"] = x;
        Item["ItemID"] = fieldRow[0].ToString();
        Item["UnitPrice"] = fieldRow[1].ToString();
        Item["Description"] = fieldRow[2].ToString();
        Item["OrderUOM"] = fieldRow[3].ToString();
        Item["OrderQty"] = fieldRow[4].ToString();
        Item.Rows.Add(aItem);

        AllItems.Tables.Add(AItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have 2 `DataTable` with the same name in your `DataSet`. If you have more than 1 `DataRow` in the `myDataset.Tables["tempTable"]`, on the second iteration of `foreach` it will try to add new `Item` datatable to your dataset, which already includes `Item` datatable, as a result you will get an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your only problem but you are using the `DataTable` as if it was a `DataRow`. `Item` is the table, it has no string-indexer, so replace

```
DataRow aItem = Item.NewRow();
Item["ID"] = 1.ToString();    
Item["LineNumber"] = x;
Item["ItemID"] = fieldRow[0].ToString();
Item["UnitPrice"] = fieldRow[1].ToString();
Item["Description"] = fieldRow[2].ToString();
Item["OrderUOM"] = fieldRow[3].ToString();
Item["OrderQty"] = fieldRow[4].ToString();
Item.Rows.Add(aItem);
```

with

```
DataRow aItem = Item.NewRow();
aItem["ID"] = 1.ToString();    
aItem["LineNumber"] = x;
aItem["ItemID"] = fieldRow[0].ToString();
aItem["UnitPrice"] = fieldRow[1].ToString();
aItem["Description"] = fieldRow[2].ToString();
aItem["OrderUOM"] = fieldRow[3].ToString();
aItem["OrderQty"] = fieldRow[4].ToString();
Item.Rows.Add(aItem);
```

---

But i assume that this is just the next error, "Datatable named “Items” already belongs to this dataset" is thrown because you are adding a table to a `DataSet` with the same name of another table. You are adding tables with the static  name  "AItem" in the loop here:

```
foreach (DataRow fieldRow in myDataset.Tables["tempTable"].AsEnumerable())
{
    // ...
    DataTable AItem = new DataTable("AItem");
    // ...
    AllItems.Tables.Add(AItem);
    // ...
}
```

I don't understand the logic, maybe it's sufficient to use the default constructor without a name.

Comment: Maybe it's me but it appears that you are recommending that I replace code with the same code.  I am missing something in your reply? - Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @user3318152: compare `aItem` with `Item` ;) You see that meaningful variable names are very important. I'd named it `newRow` instead of `aItem` and `tblItem` instead of `Item`.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. My string indexers were correct in my project but I posted them incorrectly here, however thank you for explaining. I was designating the datatable names the same because these datatables need to create a XML tag of the same name in XMLWrite function.  I am trying to create an xml structure with these datatables such as <Items><Item>datarow of record</Item><Item>datarow of record</Item></Items>. I could do this with DataAdapter.Fill method but I was trying to specify a DataRelation with the Items table.